# indexOf() need to find a keyword defined in an array within a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have an input element that allows me to do the following:

1. Filter on Angular $Scope/Array - Works
2. On using the Enter key it appends/pushes to $Scope/Array - Works
3. Identifies a keyword within the string on the input and alerts - Does Not work
   3.1 Works if i only type the keyword, example "bguser"
   3.2 Does not work if i type more than the keyword, example "Simon Edwards bguser"
4. The array for the keyword is currently defined inline

   `$scope.checkKeyword = function() {
           var elem = {name: $scope.addName.name};
           if (['bguser', 'bgadmin'].indexOf(elem.name) >= 0) {
               alert(elem.name);
           }

       };`

but I would like it injected if possible from $scope.keywordlist

```
 $scope.keywordlist = [
        {name: 'bguser'},
        {name: 'bgadmin'},
        ];
```

I need help getting this (3 & 4) to work. I have the following in [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b6s2za10/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="bgApp">
<head>
<title>List & Tag</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Local CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="./static/css/dev-style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div ng-controller="listController">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 div-title">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <h1><small>{{title}}</small></h1>
                <input type="text" ng-enter="addItem()" ng-keyup="checkKeyword()" ng-model="addName.name" class="search-query" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 div-title">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">Name of Item</div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">Tag</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 div-row" ng-repeat="item in list | filter:addName">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">{{ item.name }}</div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">{{ item.tag }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- AngularJS scripts from CDN -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

<!-- JQuery scripts from CDN -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap scripts compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Locally installed scripts --> 
<script src="./js/bgapp.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JS

```
var bgapp = angular.module('bgApp', [])

.directive('ngEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if (event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter, {
                        'event': event
                    });
                });

                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});

bgapp.controller('listController', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {

    $scope.title = 'Recent Activity';

    $scope.list = [
        {name: 'User 1', tag: 'bgUser'},
        {name: 'Admin 1', tag: 'bgAdmin'},
        {name: 'Service 1', tag: ''},
        {name: 'Project 1', tag: ''},
        {name: 'Configuration Item 1', tag: ''},
        {name: 'Task 1', tag: ''},
        {name: 'Incident 1', tag: ''},
        {name: 'Issue 1', tag: ''},
        {name: 'Known Issue 1', tag: ''},
        {name: 'Problem 1', tag: ''},
        {name: 'Knowledge Base 1', tag: ''},
        {name: 'Update 1', tag: ''},
        {name: 'Document 1', tag: ''},
        ];

    $scope.keywordlist = [
        {name: 'bguser'},
        {name: 'bgadmin'},
        ];

    $scope.addItem = function() {
        var elem = {name: $scope.addName.name};
        if ($filter('filter')($scope.list, {name: elem.name}).length == 0) {
            $scope.list.push(
                elem 
            );
            //alert(elem.name);
        }
    };

    $scope.checkKeyword = function() {
        var elem = {name: $scope.addName.name};
        if (['bguser', 'bgadmin'].indexOf(elem.name) >= 0) {
            alert(elem.name);
        }  
    };

}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enuamrate your keyword list, and check if the current keyword is within your input:

```
var elem = {name: $scope.addName.name};
    angular.forEach($scope.keywordlist, function(keyword) {
    console.log(0);
    if (elem.name.indexOf(keyword.name) > -1)
        alert(elem.name);
});
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lv7Lfhg/)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks. I do seem to get a double alert however, 1. When the keyword is typed (I need this), 2. When I hit the enter/return key (don't need this). This is probably down to the ng-keyup, do you know how to tell ng-keyup to ignore enter/return key?

Comment: Never mind I've managed to solve this one :-) When I set $scope.addName.name = ""; after the push had been completed it stopped the double alerting. Thanks again.